# blank ListItem is rendered in react native component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Im trying to render a simple list using the `ListItem` component but it doesn't seems to work , all I set is an empty list

CODE :

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center'
  }
}

  details = [
    'one',
    'two',
    'three'
  ]

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Modal
        animationType="slide"
        transparent={false}
        visible={props.modalVisible}
        onRequestClose={() => {
          alert('Modal has been closed.');
        }}>
        <View style={styles.container}>    
          <View>
            <Card containerStyle={{padding: 0}} >
              {
                details.map((i) => {
                  return (
                    <ListItem
                      key={i}
                      title={i}
                    />
                  );
                })
              }
            </Card>
          </View>
        </View>
      </Modal>
    </View>
  );
```

Comment: Can you post the code of `ListItem` component?

Comment: well , its a component from this package https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/listitem.html

Comment: Shouldn't it be `const details`?

Comment: not really its inside `class`

Comment: Even if it's inside the class, it should be declared. Can you post the complete code of this component? It'd be helpful to debug.

Comment: the problem isnt with the declaration when I change the `ListItem` to `Text` it work just fine